# ZF2 module loading performance

Tags: php, performance, class, zend-framework2, autoload

As far as I understand, every enabled module in a `ZF2` application is loaded for every request (unless one uses optimization methods such as that offered by the [zf2-lazy-loading-module](https://github.com/blanchonvincent/zf2-lazy-loading-module) module). I've been keeping an eye on modules that get published on [`modules.zendframework.org`](http://modules.zendframework.com/) and I've come across modules which offer extremely limited functionality, such as the [AkrabatFormatUkTelephone](https://github.com/akrabat/AkrabatFormatUkTelephone/blob/master/Module.php) module which purpose is to format phone numbers to UK format.

Whilst I understand development should focus on creating single purpose modules that are good at doing one thing (instead of modules which do many things but not in a very good way), I'm thinking if we start using modules which offer such limited functionality as the one mentioned, we will need to combine hundreds of modules in order to build a rich application which could be disastrous for performance. Instead I would expect this sort of functionality to be put in a class (e.g. [`Zend\I18n`](https://github.com/akrabat/AkrabatFormatUkTelephone/blob/master/Module.php)?) and loaded on demand which would be more optimized. But knowing Akrabat's reputation I'm thinking I must be missing something, hence my question:

**Is the loading of modules such as the one I mentioned significantly worse for performance than loading the same functionality via PHP classes (or is it similar due to the way ZF2 has been designed)? Does anybody have any figures (i.e. is it 5%, 10%, 15% slower) about module vs class loading performance?**

Answer (score 3):

Don't take this comment as a final answer, as hopefully someone of the ZF2 devs will shed some more insight to it, but generally only `Module.php` and usually `module.config.php` will be actively loaded. Everything else will simply be registered and be called on demand. So as long as your Module.php and module.config.php are not TOO big in filesize, the performance shouldn't be THAT big of an issue

In the case of Akrabats example, all that's happening is, the registry of a new ViewHelper. Nothing else. The same with all other view helpers inside of Zend. Performance won't really matter a lot in these cases.

Personally the Skeleton loaded with 80ms on my Webspace and with BjyAuthorize, ZfcBase, ZfcUser and my own module, the loading time ramped up to 100ms. And this is *without* any sort of memory caching enabled!

Comment: Yes hopefully someone from `ZF2` dev team will see the question and provide their insight (I'm assuming they did some performance benchmarking while designing the module system and hopefully they will be willing to share the figures with us).

Comment: I may suggest to you to head over to IRC#zftalk@freenode.net and post your question there. You should especially be looking for EvanPro, since he designed the ModuleManager

Comment: Thanks. Problem with IRC is that answers don't get the same exposure (in terms of audience and over time) as they do on StackOverflow. Hopefully EvanPro will see this question.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a module is not much more than loading any class, like Sam pointed out.
As long as you don't use anything from your module and do things right, it's just beeing registered.

**Now what does "do things right" mean?**

Just try to put a big nonsense loop inside your module classes bootstrap() method. You will see that this slows down every request on your application, because the bootstrap method of your module is called on every request and it should be used very carefully, only for light weight tasks. The purposes you usually use the bootstrap() method for, won't even slow down your app for a millisecond, but writing a file to the disk in this method could slow down your app for many seconds in each request.

If your app becomes really heavy, you should use the classmap_autoloader and some caching wherever you can. If you did "things right", you won't have any performance problems, just because you have many modules or many classes in your app. One could say, it's just all about algorithms.

Keep going on using best practices, like the one you mentioned. Usually these aren't the bottlenecks of your application, but your own algorithms and failures are.

edit:
When you're using modules from the community, you should always check them for performance issues. Even a module that seems to be very light could be a bottleneck for your application if it has bad algorithms. But the case that you're loading an additional module is not the point of it.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I would like to contribute a little bit to the reaction of Sam.

Module performance is not solely the loading of the module (which is, as pointed out quite fast), but also the communication of the modules in-between. So this question might boil down to: how slow/fast is the ServiceLocator and Event-driven system in comparison to traditional non-modulair systems?

I recall that ZF2 was build with performance in mind. For instance, the ServiceLocator registers factories, so that objects can be instantiated on-the-fly. So this requires only a few extra in-memory objects and instantiations, I guess this does not impact the total performance for your application much. The EventManager works in much the same way and I have not seen it being overloaded with registered events, even in large applications.

What might slow down, on the other hand, is the loading of the modules configuration. I figure that using a cache might solve this problem. I'm not sure but maybe Zend Optimizer might do this already.

So, in short, applications should scale pretty wel, provided that modules behave well, and do not over-register events or misuse the ServiceLocator.

Answer (score 0):

From the MVC component's perspective there are no modules at all! There's one big configuration file - a result of merge of every module's configuration. Unless your modules don't have a `onBootstrap` method or don't do much, module loading is as fast as invoking `new Module` on every one of them, which is painless and memory inexpensive.

The configuration merge procedure, which I mentioned above, happens only in DEV mode which is enabled by default.

There are number of tricks also to speed up your ZF2 application, like:

1. Enable merged config cache
2. Use [EdpSuperluminal module](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpSuperluminal)
3. Return the ViewModel objects from actions, not arrays
4. Explicitly set the template name on the ViewModel
5. Use template maps instead of template path stack alone
6. Route order in the config matters! Its a LIFO queue (last in-first out).
7. Make sure you don't load Console modules in HTTP context.
8. Let the [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) do the autoloading, not ZF2

... and more. There's a [quite good talk](http://www.masterzendframework.com/reviews/maximising-zend-framework-2-performance-phpuk14/) by [Gary Hockin](http://blog.hock.in/) on the ZF2 app performance.

Authorization modules will surely slow down your app. There are number of things going down under the hood: the identity of the user needs to be fetched (from the database?), user needs to be authenticated agains your rules. Surely you can speed things up by using memcached or such, but this requires to have some knowledge about the lifecycle of the ZF2 application, about the modules you use, etc.

Also there is Zend Framework 3 going to be released soon, some things will go faster, but don't expect much. A lot of overhead is a result of your lack of knowledge about ZF2 - no offense!